# java.io.IOException CreateFile failed with error 3

Tags: java, scala, sbt, java-home

I have a windows 10 machine, and I have JDK 1.8 installed in it. I also have scala 2.11.12. I have installed SBT 1.2.8 and all 3 are visible in the control panel.

The JAVA_HOME is properly set.

However when I try to run `sbt sbtVersion`

I get error as

`[error] java.io.IOException: CreateFile() failed with error 3`

Am I missing something here ? What is the fix to this problem ?

Comment: Are you running the command in a sbt project? If so can you provide _build.properties_ as well as if you doing specific stuff in the _build.sbt_?

Comment: Might want to have a look to https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3871 as well although you seem to use a version of sbt where bug is fixed.